# Tcl error : wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"

Tags: unix, tcl, vmd

I tried to run the following Tcl script and got the error: wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"

What does this mean?

Note: The script includes terms specific to VMD program, such as mol and resid. Please disregard them.

```
#count water molecules between chain A and chain C or between #chain B and chain C


set input_file [open ./name_3_pdb_chain_renamed.dat r]

set data [read $input_file]
set data [split $data "\n"]
close $input_file

set chain_list [lindex $data 0]

cd 7_count_water

set outfile [open count_water3.dat w]


set chain_compare ""

set pdblen [llength $chain_list]

for {set i 0} {$i<$pdblen} {incr i} {
    set pid [lindex [lindex $chain_list $i] 0]

    set len [llength [lindex $chain_list $i]]

    mol load pdb ../2_chain_rename/${pid}_chain_revised.pdb


    mol modstyle 0 top NewCartoon



    if {$len==4} {
        set chain_compare [lappend chain_compare $pid]
    }

    set 11 [atomselect top all]

    set mid [$11 molid]

    mol delete $mid
}




set lll [llength $chain_compare]

for {set j 0} {$j< $lll} {incr j} {

    set pid [lindex $chain_compare $j]

    mol load pdb ../2_chain_rename/${pid}_chain_revised.pdb

    set 11 [atomselect top "chain A and name CA"]

    set res_len [llength [$11 get resid]]

    set res_id [$11 get resid]

    #residue length for chain C
    set ag [atomselect top "chain C and name CA"]
    set ag_len [llength [$ag get resid]]
    set ag_id [$ag get resid]


    #loop water between chain A and chain C
    for {set k 0} {$k<$res_len} {incr k} {

        set water_around_a [atomselect top "{resname HOH and {within 5.0 of {chain A and resid [lindex $res_id $k]} and {within 5.0 of chain C}}} "]


        set water_around_a_resid [$water_around_a get resid]
        set water_around_a_resname [$water_around_a get resname]

        #loop antigen residues around water
        for {set g 0} {$g < $ag_len} {incr g} {

          set ag_around_water [atomselect top "{chain C and resid [lindex $ag_id $g] and {within 5.0 of {resname HOH and {within 5.0 of {chain A and resid [lindex $res_id $k]}}}}} "]

            set ag_around_water resid [$ag_around_water get resid]

            set ag_around_water_resname [$ag_around_water get resname]


            puts $outfile "$pid [lindex $res_id $k] [lindex [$11 get resname] $k] $ag_around_water_resname A: $water_around_a_resname"
       }
    }



    set b11 [atomselect top "chain B and name CA"]

    set b_res_len [llength [$b11 get resid]]

    set b_res_id [$b11 get resid]

    #residue length for chain C
    set ag [atomselect top "chain C and name CA"]
    set ag_len [llength [$ag get resid]]
    set ag_id [$ag get resid]

    for {set k 0} {$k<$res_len} {incr k} {


        set water_around_b [atomselect top "{resname HOH and {within 5.0 of {chain B and resid [lindex $b_res_id $k]} and {within 5.0 of chain C}}} "]

        set water_around_b_resid [$water_around_b get resid]
        set water_around_b_resname [$water_around_b get resname]

        #loop antigen residues around water
        for {set g 0} {$g < $ag_len} {incr g} {

             set ag_around_water [atomselect top "{chain C and resid [lindex $ag_id $g] and {within 5.0 of {resname HOH and {within 5.0 of {chain B and resid [lindex $b_res_id $k]}}}}} "]


            set ag_around_water resid [$ag_around_water get resid]

            set ag_around_water_resname [$ag_around_water get resname]

            puts $outfile "$pid [lindex $b_res_id $k] [lindex [$b11 get resname] $k] $ag_around_water_resname A: $water_around_b_resname"


        }

    }

}


close $outfile

cd ..
```

Thank you

Comment: One of your `set` commands has too many (or too few arguments). Use a debugger or puts to narrow down how far your script gets before reaching this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That message:

```
wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
```

is a standard error thrown when a built-in command gets the wrong number of arguments to evaluate. In this case, it's coming from the `set` command, and indicates that you've either said `set` on its own, or given more than two further arguments to it.

If you examine the stack trace (usually printed with the error message when using standard `tclsh`, though it's changeable with user code) then you'll get told where the problem happened. *However,* in this case we can look through and see that this line near the bottom of the script:

```
            set ag_around_water resid [$ag_around_water get resid]
```

has what appears to be a space instead of an underscore in the variable name. Now, spaces *are* legal in variable names, but then the variable name needs to be quoted, and that can get a bit annoying. It's usually best to avoid using them like that. Without quoting, Tcl doesn't know that that's meant to be one word; the generic parsing layer decides there's really four words there (`set`, `ag_around_water`, `resid` and the complex `[$ag_around_water get resid]`) and tells `set` to deal with that, which it doesn't like.

Remember, Tcl's generic syntactic parsing happens first, before command arguments are interpreted semantically. ***Always.***

Answer (score 3):

The line `set ag_around_water resid [$ag_around_water get resid]` needs to be changed. You probably want `ag_around_water_resid` instead.